# Bean configuration for Apache Extras Cassandra-JDBC

Tags: spring, jdbc, cassandra, javabeans

I looked around their site http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/cassandra-jdbc/ but couldn't find any documentation for configuring a data source bean such as

```
    <spring:bean id="mySqlDataSource"
         class="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource">
         <spring:property name="url"
              value="jdbc:mysql://${mysql.host}:${mysql.port}/${mysql.database}?user=${mysql.user}&amp;password=${mysql.pwd}" />
    </spring:bean>
```

Is there any documentation anywhere or does anyone know how to write one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CassandraDataSource doesn't seem to have a default constructor, so you'll need to pass everything in:

```
<spring:bean id="cassDataSource"
     class="org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDataSource">
     <constructor-arg value="host">
     <constructor-arg type="int" value="port">
     <constructor-arg value="keyspace">
     <constructor-arg value="user">
     <constructor-arg value="password">
     <constructor-arg value="version">
</spring:bean>
```

(I haven't tested this, but it's basically what you'd need to do).

Comment: Yup, you may have to set it to null, or the empty string ("")

Comment: I'm using:

<spring:beans>
        <spring:bean id="cassDataSource" name="Bean" class="org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDataSource">
            <spring:constructor-arg type="String" value="myHost"/>
            <spring:constructor-arg type="int" value="9160"/>
            <spring:constructor-arg type="String" value="demo"/>
            <spring:constructor-arg type="String" value="myName"/>
            <spring:constructor-arg type="String" value="foo"/>
            <spring:constructor-arg type="String" value="1.0.10"/> 
        </spring:bean>
    </spring:beans>

but I'm getting

Comment: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name        defined in URL Could not resolve matching constructor (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)

Comment: Looks like I have a newer version than you; try omitting the last version argument.

Answer (score 0):

I found this on Google, and the info is slightly out of date, so I thought I'd update it.  The arguments have changed.   The best way I found to figure out what arguments it's expecting is to use the source, which you can get off of GitHub using an address like:

https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/cassandra-jdbc/source/browse/src/main/java/org/apache/cassandra/cql/jdbc/CassandraDataSource.java?name=v1.2.5

There's a selector on that page where you can pick the version number you downloaded (that link brings you to 1.2.5).  You need to satisfy all the constructor arguments.